# MATLAB save image from GUI using push button

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to save an image from a designated axes. I keep getting `You may not have permission to write` error. Here is my code for the save as push button:

```
axes(handles.axes3);
[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*bmp', 'Save As');
Name = fullfile(FileName, PathName);
imwrite(handles.TReg, Name, 'bmp');
```

Also, `handles.TReg` is a transformed image defined on another function.

I cannot seem to find my error here, any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Edit**
If I use the code:

```
axes(handles.axes3);
[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*bmp', 'Save As');
Name = fullfile(FileName, PathName);
imwrite(handles.TReg, 'Name', 'bmp');
```

The file will save as Name.bmp in the proper directory. However I did notice that when I try saving with the original code, the error also reads (I missed this bit sorry):

```
Can't open file "Image1\C:\Users\Shinobii\Documents\MATLAB\" for writing.
```

I think the pathname should read like

```
"C:\Users\Shinobii\Documents\MATLAB\Image1"
```

could this be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small mistake:

```
[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*.bmp', 'Save As'); %# <-- dot
Name = fullfile(PathName,FileName);  %# <--- reverse the order of arguments
imwrite(img, Name, 'bmp');
```

Also its a good idea to check that the user didn't cancel the dialog box:

```
[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*.bmp', 'Save As');
if PathName==0, return; end    %# or display an error message
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the path and the filename and try to save an image by calling imwrite by hand. This probably has nothing to do with the GUI and the button callback but with either the file permissions and/or the path name.

Comment: I have edited my question to include more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Again, it seems like a silly mistake I should have found earlier.

```
axes(handles.axes3);
[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*bmp', 'Save As');
Name = fullfile(PathName, FileName);
imwrite(handles.TReg, Name, 'bmp');
```

In `Name` I needed to flip the `FileName` and `PathName`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry Georg, I was away from the computer for awhile. Amro is a saint, and always has the answers!